# Using data retrieved from custom action in installation location

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-installer, installation-path

I have created a custom action for installing my service to windows. I have a custom dialog in the setup that retrieves a name for the instance of the service.

When installing I want to install the product to the following path: `[company name][product][instance]`, where `instance` is the name that I retrieve from the custom action. I can retrieve the value entered for `instance` but need to know how to specify it as a folder in the installation directory.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

pie154

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the instance name in an [installer property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for example INSTANCE. If you are using a Windows Installer dialog to retrieve it, you can simply use the edit box control property.

This way your default installation path can be something like this:

```
[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer] [ProductName] [INSTANCE]
```

Comment: Thank you, would you be able to direct me to some c# code that saves into an installer property.

Comment: C# custom actions cannot modify installer properties. This is usually done through win32 DLL custom actions: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx . I think WiX toolset may offer some properties support for C# custom actions, but I'm not sure if it does what you need.